# How to tie two typescript generics together

Tags: typescript, generics

Let's say I have two base types that represent entities that do not share any data, f.e. request and response to some imaginary API. But, each type derived from one entity has a pair of another derived entity, f.e.

```
type Request = { token: string }
type Response = { resultCode: number }

type UserRequest = Request & { userId: number }
type UserResponse = Response & { userName: string }
```

It would be nice to have a type that would tie UserRequest and UserResponse together, f.e.

```
type Query<Rq extends Request, Rs extends Response> = {}
type UserQuery = Query<UserRequest, UserResponse>
```

And use that type in a function signature without the need to specify the both types, something like this:

```
function processQuery<Q extends Query>(request: Q.Rq): Q.Rs {
    return {} as Q.Rs;
}

let userResponse = processQuery<UserQuery>({
    token: "123",
    userId: 1
});
console.log(userResponse.userName);
```

Is this possible in today's TypeScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't really understand your use case exactly, so I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about things.  That said, you certainly can represent such type manipulations.  Here's one way:

```
type Query<RQ extends Request = Request, RS extends Response = Response> = {
    rq: RQ;
    rs: RS;
}
```

Notice that the `Query<RQ, RS>` type has to depend [structurally](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing) on the `RQ` and `RS` type parameters.  You really don't ever want a type definition like `type Foo<T> = {}` where the type to which it evaluates is [empty](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-all-types-assignable-to-empty-interfaces) or otherwise [independent of its type parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--).  So what I've done is given `Query<RQ, RS>` a `rq` property of type `RQ`, and a `rs` property of type `RS`.

Also, I've used [generic parameter defaults](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) so that just `Query` by itself means `Query<Request, Response>`.  The following definition remains unchanged:

```
type UserQuery = Query<UserRequest, UserResponse>;
```

And now `processQuery` can use [lookup types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) to pull out the `rq` and `rs` property types of `Q`.  TypeScript doesn't support dot notation for property lookups; instead you use bracket notation acting on string literals.  Anyway, if `Q` is specified as `Query<T, U>`, then the type `Q["rq"]` will be `T` and the type `Q["rs"]` will be `U`.  So it looks like this:

```
function processQuery<Q extends Query>(request: Q["rq"]): Q["rs"] {
    return {} as Query["rs"]; // what's this?
}
```

And so this behaves as you want:

```
let userResponse = processQuery<UserQuery>({
    token: "123",
    userId: 1
});
console.log(userResponse.userName);
```

This seems to require that you manually specify the `UserQuery` type in the call to `userResponse`, since there's no way the compiler will be able to infer `Q` from the value passed in as the `request` parameter (it can maybe infer the type of `rq`, but there's no place from which to infer `rs`.)  But since you were already doing that in your example code I guess that's not an issue for you.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBlAFgSwgGwCZIG8AoJUpAFwE8ZkAlCARwFdpykBeQigewGsJgALiRRyAJwzAA5kgC+JMlRpJ6sbsCjJOBJGOhNs5AMLdcEYcCZgARhDFyiC0kuQBVTWPrNWHFYxaiSABkXEweAJK4Fla29vJkFNRuHqow6pq+qenIITphdgBy4OYi4pIy8k6JygCKLGKUADy0NUgQAB7kArhQft6BnF4B5AA0Kihtnd29WRpafmpzAHy+xAkJYgzCLQDcVRtQ2yh7CfGKSUjudnV2lL43DY1Xnv6sY8+zmkt7VQBmTMB4OQMOokDAxNxEFAoA8mq0Ol1gD0kLClgAKPT9cjCGoAbQARJt8QBdACUOIJYigJMI+zIenITDEwEIsiQIF6sMp1OJOyQAHp+UgAO5oEDkADkvXImCgAH4qpUEtgIGx8i9FhlOODIdAYfUms9UWi1utnHwBMJ8QBGABMAGZ8SM6aR1ZFhNbFaSTmR4OluCqAHTYbhSNHqz4QQPqoqQb2OWRAA)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for